# How to edit the files that are generated by a Site Content Type in a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, document-set

*Situation*:

1. I have created a **Document Set Content Type** and added the neccessary files to it
2. I have added the document Set Content Type to the **Document Library**
3. I can make a new document group using the document type specified above, this will copy over the documents into a new box with all the templates the consultant needs.

*Question*:

How can I edit the templates I have specified in the **Document Set Content Type**?

*Goal*

The files that the user creates by using this functionality need to populate the templates with information that was specified in sharepoint.
In human terms: I need sharepoint to make a copy of the documents for a new project WITH the information the user specifies such as **Customer name** or **Project Name** on all documents.